# Video file uploading in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I made changes to my `php.ini` file as follows:

```
upload_max_filesize = 60M
post_max_size = 61M
```

But only KB files get uploaded, not MB files

......

Comment: Did you restart your (most likely Apache) web server after making these changes?

Comment: Some host environments have several php.ini files. Are you sure to have picked the right one? phpinfo() will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your required size in MB to KB and see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to restart your host server after changes in .ini file

Answer (score -3):

Rathen than using Mega Byte, use 60000

Comment: You should know everything as STRICT as possible before advancing. You should learn about Byte,  the conversion. That is what i mean, :)